# is there any way to interact with code.InteractiveConsole

Tags: python, python-2.7, gevent

I am using gevent library for webserver. The backdoor server in gevent library starts a interactive console using the code module(code.InteractiveConsole).

I would like to know if there is a way to interact with that console over network?

Answer (score 1):

Due to limited understanding at the time of writing question, it was put that way.

Since gevent BackdoorServer inherits StreamServer one can connect to it through socket module and execute the commands in normal way.

Something like:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(('127.0.0.1', 111111))
data =  sock.recv(160)
#print the banner
print data
#execute a command
sock.sendall('print "hi"\n')
amount_received = 0 
amount_expected = 500 
while amount_received < amount_expected:
    data =  sock.recv(160)
    amount_received += len(data)
    print data
```